# The height of the Mandelbrot Set

Tags: complex-numbers, fractals, complex-dynamics

A simple question, but one I am unable to find the answer to; What is 
$$\sup\{y:x+y\cdot i \in M\}$$
Where $M$ is the Mandelbrot set. How is this constant calculated? Is it a known constant? Etc...

Comment: This [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/10buxc/what_is_the_highest_vertical_coordinate_on_the/) claims the point is approximately $-0.20710786709396773 + 1.12275706363259748$ with the real part close to the principal value of $i^i$